# What is the right change of variables which allows to obtain this expression?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Let
$$f(x) =\frac{1}{\omega_{N-1}} \frac{\log\left(\frac{d}{|x|}\right)}{(\log j)^{1/N}}\quad\mbox{ if }\quad d/j <|x|< d$$
where $\omega_{N-1}$ denotes the area of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^N, j\geq 2$ and $d>0$.
Why the integral $\int f(x)^k dx$ can be written in this way
$$\int f(x)^k dx = \frac{\omega_{N-1}^{1-k/N} d^N}{(\log j)^{k/N}} \int_{1/j}^1 (-\log s)^k s^{N-1} ds?$$

Could anyone please please help me? I guess there is a change of variables somewhere, but I am not able to understand what is the right choice.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to polar coordinates,
\begin{align*}\int_{d/j<|x|<d}\left(\frac{1}{\omega_{N-1}}\frac{\log\left(\frac{d}{|x|}\right)}{(\log j)^{1/N}}\right)^k\, dx&=\frac{\omega_{N-1}^{-k}}{(\log j)^{k/N}}\int_{d/j<|x|<d}\left(\log\left(\frac{d}{|x|}\right)\right)^k\, dx\\
&=\frac{\omega_{N-1}^{-k}}{(\log j)^{k/N}}\int\limits_{S^{n-1}}\int\limits_{d/j}^j\left(\log\left(\frac{d}{r}\right)\right)^kr^{N-1}\, drd\sigma
\end{align*} Let $s(r)=r/d.$ Observe that $s(d/j)=1/j$, $s(d)=1,$ and $d\ ds=dr.$ Using this change of variables,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\omega_{N-1}^{-k}}{(\log j)^{k/N}}\int\limits_{S^{N-1}}\int\limits_{d/j}^j\left(\log\left(\frac{d}{r}\right)\right)^kr^{N-1}\, drd\sigma&=\frac{\omega_{N-1}^{-k}}{(\log j)^{k/N}}\int\limits_{S^{N-1}}\int\limits_{1/j}^1\left(\log(s^{-1})\right)^k(sd)^{N-1}d\, dsd\sigma\\
&=\frac{\omega_{N-1}^{-k}d^N}{(\log j)^{k/N}}\int\limits_{S^{N-1}}\int\limits_{1/j}^1\left(-\log s\right)^ks^{N-1}\, dsd\sigma\\
&=\frac{\omega_{N-1}^{1-k}d^N}{(\log j)^{k/N}}\int\limits_{1/j}^1\left(-\log s\right)^ks^{N-1}\, ds
\end{align*}
The power of the area is slightly off from what you stated, but I see no way of getting a power of $N$ in there, unless you meant to define your function a little bit differently.